# Mixing RequireJS shims with TypeScript - how to compile for production?

Tags: typescript, requirejs

I'm new to using TypeScript and RequireJS, and I'm in the process of converting a large application written in Marionette/Backbone.

I'm confused by the relationship between TypeScript dependencies within each ts file, and dependencies in the RequireJS config shim for non-AMD compliant files. My app loads fine using individual files and dependencies within ts files and the requirejs config shim section.

I've tried compiling my TypeScript files into a single output file; is the ts transpiler aware of the dependencies as defined in shim section?  It doesn't seem to be as my single output file doesn't have all the required files.

Is this the wrong approach to take?

thanks...

Comment: My understanding is that tsc will only combine the TS files it transpiles.  If you want to include other files, like the ones mentioned in the shims, you'd need to use a build tool.  But in that case you wouldn't need the shim.  Is your goal to produce a single file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Well, I would like to create a single file output for much of the app.  I have some utility files that are shared by the different apps in our suite of apps (each app is equal to a page).  I wanted to create bundles for those utilities (e.g., a jquery plus plugins bundle, a bundle of in house utilities, etc..).  And a singe file for app specific code.

I've started to look at using requirejs for specifying bundles, but i'm not clear on what to use to build all of this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try and make the TypeScript compiler do the bundling process. Instead I would have a two step build process.

1. TypeScript files to javascript.
2. Use r.js to bundle and minify all of your files to one .js file.

You can find the r.js stuff here:
http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#download

Answer (score 0):

Just an add on to Mark's answer with real life production requireJS setup including shim:

run typescript compiler:

```
tsc -p .
```

with the following project level
**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "scripts/dist",
}
```

next, this r.js command would do the job:

```
node r.js -o buildSpec.js name=src/init mainConfigFile=deps.js baseUrl=../
```

with the following **deps.js**

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: "scripts",

    // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
    // scripts that do not call define() to register a module
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        chartJs: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min',
        appRouter: 'infra/appRouter',
        paymentsHub: 'infra/paymentsHub'
    }
});
```

**buildSpec.js:**

```
({
    out: "../target/app-optimized.js",
    include:['someExternalModule'],
    paths: {
       jquery: 'lib/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min'
    }
})
```

**src/init.js:**

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: window.siteVersion,
    waitSeconds: 20
});

require(['scripts/controller'], function () { ... });
```